# Samsung Music Controls Widget not working properly

Tags: android, android-notification.mediastyle, samsung

I have a working app with notification media controls. I am properly using `Notification.MediaStyle()`. Everything works well on Google Pixel 4a. However Samsung devices are showing their own system/default controls on **lock screen**. Buttons are wrong, metadata is missing and they are not usable.

So the question is how do I make them work or how do I disable them? I was not able to find any related documentation.

Comment: Kosur, did you find any solution ? The lock screen controls work fine from Sample apps for media3. But my app is not able to control. I am using media session. Happening samsung devices only, other device seem to work fine